# Save images from listview to a folder

Tags: c#

I had this listview and a button. There are also several images inside the listview. I want to save the images from the listview inside the folder when the button is pressed. And I don't know how to do it. Could you please help me out? Thanks. This is the code I use to insert images to the listview.

```
OpenFileDialog opend1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        opend1.Filter = "Image Files(*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF|All files (*.*)|*.*";

        opend1.Multiselect = true;

        if (opend1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {                

            listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;

            imageList.ImageSize = new Size(100, 100);

            for (int c = 0; c < opend1.FileNames.Length; c++)
            {
                Image i = Image.FromFile(opend1.FileNames[c].ToString());

                Image img = i.GetThumbnailImage(100, 100, null, new IntPtr());

                imageList.Images.Add(img);

            }

            listView1.LargeImageList = imageList;
            ListViewItem lstItem = new ListViewItem();
            lstItem.ImageIndex = imageList.Images.Count-1;
            listView1.Items.Add(lstItem);

            listView1.Refresh();

        }
```

Comment: Too vague, no code.  How'd the images get in the list view?

Comment: @Patrick Quirk  I had added the code I use to insert images to listview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each image in your image list (imageList.Images) call this (with your own supplied directory and file name):

```
img.Save(@"C:\MyImage.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (Image image in listView1.LargeImageList.Images)
{
    string filename = ""; // make this whatever you need...
    image.Save(filename);
}
```